# Sending SMS via combination of Sinch and Parse

Tags: parse-platform, sms, parse-cloud-code, sinch

Me and my colleagues have been at out wits end trying to send an SMS through Parse which in turn should call Sinch and send the SMS.

Ideally speaking there is to be a cloud code at our Parse backend. This cloud code will be invoked by user through our (iOS + Android) app. When invoked this will inturn call the Sinch SMS sendMessage Function.

Is it necessary to buy a number to send an inbound SMS??

Because no matter what we try, nothing is working out.

If anyone knows of any alternative way working it out do please let us know.

Comment: Can you share some code, if you like you mail christian@sinch.com and I can look at your particular account

Comment: Hi @cjensen my colleague has posted the cloud end  side of it on christian.jensen@digitalinformation.se. Looking forward for your thought on it.